# NCBI blast for exact match of short sequence

Tags: bioinformatics, blast

I'm trying to Blast for exact matches to the sequence: 'ATTGNNNNGCAAACCA' in the human transcriptome using NCBI Blast on its 'refseq_rna' database. However, when I do a basic query I get "No significant similarity found."

Note the N's in the middle of the sequence, if I get rid of those N's, yielding the sequence 'AGCGGATTGCAAAGCAAACCA', I get a match in the 3' UTR of the human MeCP2 gene (which is correct). I don't understand why adding the N's here make it not work.

I looked at the help section and I believe this may be due to shorter sequences being less "statistically significant". Statistical significance of output is completely irrelevant to me, so I set 'Expect Value' to 100000000000000. However, I still get the same result.

I also tried to modify the HTML of the page to allow me to submit a word size of 4 to the form. This went through, but I still got "No significant similarity found".

Could someone help me out with this? I feel like searching for a short sequence shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: You are asking a question about a piece of software which is extremely well documented. What does the documentation say about searches with wild cards?

Comment: it says absolutely nothing

Comment: Well you might email their help desk. They are quite good about replying to queries in my experience, although my own have been of a different sort.

Comment: The second sequence is not the first sequence with the N's removed, should it be?

Comment: no it's with the N's replaced with 4 bases to make it the MeCP2 sequence

Comment: This was answered in the bioinformatics StackExchange: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14423/ncbi-blast-for-exact-match-of-a-short-sequence

Comment: @MikeFlynn Please tell Maximilian Press that 4^4 = 256

Comment: You don't usually use BLAST for exact matches. I would rather suggest that you simply do a regex match using any programming language you like. Since this question has already been answered in [bioinformatics.se], I won't elaborate further.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is cross posted (and answered) in [bioinformatics.se]. (https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/14423/ncbi-blast-for-exact-match-of-a-short-sequence)